# Add UNIQUE constraint to MySQL db with 7500 records that are not unique

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Because of race condition issues in `find_or_initialize_by(key: ...)`, I have around 7500 records that are not unique. Please advise on the best way to remove the duplicates and add a UNIQUE constraint to `key` in the table. Is there anything else I should think of?

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "key", null: false
    t.bigint "parent_key"
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_posts_on_key"
    t.index ["parent_key"], name: "index_posts_on_parent_key"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
  end
```

Comment: This is too broad. Please provide the structure of your table and sample data so we can provide an accurate solution.

Comment: Search SO for `[mysql] remove duplicates` and you'll find many solutions.

Comment: @GMB thank you for suggestion! updated

Answer (score 0):

To delete duplicate records, you can use the `DELETE ... FROM ... JOIN` syntax:

```
DELETE p1 
FROM posts p1
INNER JOIN posts p2 
WHERE p1.key = p2.key AND p1.created_at > p2.created_at;
```

This will delete duplicates on `key` while retaining the record with the earlier `created_at`.

Then you can add the `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD CONSTRAINT posts_key_unique UNIQUE(key);
```

Or better yet, make the `key` column the primary key of the table (since the table does not seem to have a PK yet):

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(key);
```

Comment: What if there are multiple duplications? Same record x7?

Comment: @assa: if there are 7 duplicate records, this will delete 6 out of 7 records (and keep the one with the earliest creation date)